# React Native Styling to CSS (shadowOffset/shadowRadius to box-shadow)

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, styling

I have some React Native styling code, but not sure how to properly translate this style to React/CSS. It appears `box-shadow` is the correct CSS element.

**CSS Box Shadow:**

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp

**React Native Docs:**

https://reactnative.dev/docs/shadow-props

**React Native Style:**

```css
shadowColor: '#E5E5E5',
shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 1 },
shadowOpacity: 0.1,
shadowRadius: 5,
```

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/709

Comment: I'm not using the styled-components library. Just using plain CSS